# Convert Powershell to exe with parameters

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, exe

I have a powershell script which looks like this:

```
param(
[string]$fullpath,
[string]$username,
[string]$password,
[string]$driveletter = "P:",
[bool]$storedrive = $False)

$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network

$net.MapNetworkDrive($driveletter, $fullpath, $storedrive, $username, $password)
```

I tried to convert it to an executable with [PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1) which worked fine.

If I try to run the .exe with `name.exe -fullpath "\\192.168.1.120\share" -username "administrator" -password "test123"` I get the error message `Networkname not found`

If I compile the following code to an executable

```
param(
[string]$fullpath = "\\192.168.1.120\share",
[string]$username = "administrator",
[string]$password ="test123",
[string]$driveletter = "P:",
[bool]$storedrive = $False)

$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network

$net.MapNetworkDrive($driveletter, $fullpath, $storedrive, $username, $password)
```

...and run the .exe - it works and I get the network drive shown in the Explorer....

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Regards
Markus

Comment: Looks like problem with parameters. Try and add a `write-host` to the non-working version to display the parameter set passed to `MapNetworkDrive`. Does the output look sensible?

Comment: when i try to add the ´write-host "$net.MapNetworkDrive($driveletter, $fullpath, $storedrive, $username, $password)"´ and compile it to an exe it shows nothing ... when i run it in powershell it works fine and i get the output printed

Comment: Instead of `Write-Host "$net.MapNetworkDrive(...)"`, try the simpler `Write-Host "fullpath=$fullpath; username=$username; password=$password; driveletter=$driveletter; storedrive=$storedrive"` - you want to ensure that the parameters you're passing are correctly assigned within the EXE.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, now I'm justing using this script

```
param(
[string]$driveletter,
[string]$fullpath,
[string]$username,
[string]$password)

$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network

$net.MapNetworkDrive($driveletter, $fullpath, $false, $username, $password)
```

which I convert into the .exe
This works fine.
The .exe uses the following "parameters"

```
run.exe "P:" "\\192.168.1.120\share" "administrator" "test123"
```

There is some problem with converting of the boolean. However, it works now the way I want to.